# default_groups in ckan harvesting configuration

Tags: ckan, harvest, geonetwork

I'm using Ckan 2.5.1 with harvesting extension and Geonetwork harvesting extension. In harvesting configuration page I set

```
{
 "api_version": 3,
 "cql":"any LIKE 'urbanistica'",
 "default_groups":["urbanistica"]
}
```

in order to filter datasets to harvest and to assign them to existing group `urbanistica`.

All filtered datasets are created into ckan, from a geonetwork CSW, but no one dataset is assigned to urbanistica group.

It seems `default_groups` is ignored because of no error is logged into log files.

I'm missing other configurations or settings (as in `production.ini`)?

Answer (score 0):

You're using [ckanext-spatial's CSW harvester](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial/blob/master/ckanext/spatial/harvesters/csw.py), which accepts the `cql` option, but not the `default_groups` option, which is why it doesn't work.

You're probably getting confused with the [CKAN harvester](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/master/ckanext/harvest/harvesters/ckanharvester.py) (i.e. CKAN harvesting from other CKAN servers), which does accept the `default_groups` option.

You could probably easily copy the `default_groups` code from the CKAN harvester to the CSV harvester (well actually into its base class [SpatialHarvester](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial/blob/master/ckanext/spatial/harvesters/base.py)), and submit that as a Pull Request. It already has default_tags and default_extras, so adding default_groups makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. 
I finally realized I'm using [ckanext-geonetwork](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/ckanext-geonetwork/) that has its own configuration parameters, different from CKAN harvester.
Corresponding of 'default_groups' is ['group_mapping'](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/ckanext-geonetwork/wiki)
Teresa